# Easiest Driver Back Up solution?

Tags: windows, software-rec, drivers

I've to faced kinda of missing drivers after formatted Windows ..

Especially, Graphic Drivers, Touch-pad driver, finger print driver and so forth are sensitive . They do not work without installing drivers. I can even download at its official website . But some drivers are not found in the website.  .. Thus, I'm looking for a solution ( may be a software : free ) that can backup my drivers effectively ( if it can do with schedule, it'll be great) and can restore easily locally . Espcially, for Win XP and Vista.

Any suggestions with your experience will be appreciated really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to keep it simple, the opensource [driverbackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drvback/) is probably what i'd recommend. Its quite helpful on my non DIY or thinkpad boxen

Answer (score 1):

[Driver Max](http://www.drivermax.com/) is an excellent program with a good free version...you can backup and restore drivers with minimal effort...used it successfully when upgrading from Vista to 7...